# Expanding single row in pandas dataframe by splitting one column into several component

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a sample of my dataframe as below:

```
Product Category    Books, VHS videotapes, Software, Video Games
Per Shipment                                               $4.99
Per Item                                                   $2.49
Per Item Remarks                           Heavy media surcharge
```

This should the data for one row in my dataframe, each row has four columns.

What I want to do is to split the `Product Category` item into several components by `,`, and then this row will be expanded into four, data for the remaining three columns will be the same.

I have written a explicit loop like below:

```
for index, row in raw_table.iterrows():
   temp_product = row['Product Category'].split(',')
   temp_product = [re.sub('^ ','',x) for x in temp_product]
   row['Product Category'] = temp_product
```

I succeed in spliting the `Product Category` column for each row into multiple components, but I dunno how to "expand" each single row, the line `row['Product Category'] = temp_product` is not working.

I missed the `data.frame` function in R, which I will do in this way in R:

```
row.mod <- data.frame('product_category'=temp_product,
                      'per_shipment'=row['per_shipment'],
                      'per_item'=row['per_item'],
                      'per_item_remarks'=row['per_item_remarks'])
```

Can anyone enlighten me on how to do this in python? Thanks!

Comment: That does not look like effective R code. It would not process that text file.